# NSUserDefaults not saving in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I'm having this issue with `NSUserDefaults`. It is saving the defaults until I kill the app in the background then when I return all the defaults are gone. They are also gone every time a build a new version onto my device. But again, they are there within app so long as I don't kill it in the background. It's working fine in iOS 6. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you synchronizing? Technically you shouldn't have to, but worth a try.

Comment: Yeah I am. So strange.

Comment: Are you define `NSUserDefaults * defaults;` in your header? Or using `[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]`

Comment: I am having the same issue using cocos2x (3.0). Even calling `synchronize` does not solve the issue.

Comment: did you find why you were not able to save in user defaults

Comment: What type of value you want to save ? İs it kimd of model or İmage.  Or it is just primitive type ?

Answer (score 0):

Take your value in string(or any other as per your requirement) and save the string in user defaults

```
NSUserDefaults *userdefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];        
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dicUser objectForKey:@"device_token"]];
[userdefault setObject:str forKey:@"YOURKEY"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't your code, so i am giving example which is perfectly working for me on iOS 7, give it a try. Hopefully works for you too.

For saving boolean value

```
bool flag = YES;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:flag forKey:@"flag"];
```

For retrieving boolean value

```
bool flag = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"flag"];
```

Answer (score -2):

make sure few things like you have declared the `userDefaults` before using it and if you've taken that in you `AppDelegate` file then here is a sample code how i am saving values and it works fine so try it this way

```
APP_DELEGATE.userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[APP_DELEGATE.userDefaults setObject:@"unChecked" forKey:@"CheckMark"];
[APP_DELEGATE.userDefaults synchronize];
```

here `APP_DELEGATE` is declared like this in my `AppDelegate.h` file

```
#define APP_DELEGATE ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

hope it helps!

Comment: whats the reason to save `NSUserDefaults` to app delegate?